# Loop in different type of array to find matched one

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data

I'm trying to add a favorite button to my application using CoreData.

I have tableView and added favorite button inside of it to save the label when I press that specific row. I saved it successfully. But I want to populate the CoreData just once for that specific row.

```
           var checkFav = [Fav]()
```

I created an array with Type Fav which is name of my class for CoreData to populate items I have to check they appear just once.

```
           let result = try context.fetch(Fav.fetchRequest())
            checkFav = result as! [Fav]


            if checkFav.isEmpty{
                let fav = Fav(context: context)
                fav.name = name
                appDelegate.saveContext()
            }
```

Above you see i populated the array.

```
        do{
            let result = try context.fetch(Fav.fetchRequest())
            checkFav = result as! [Fav]


            if checkFav.isEmpty{
                let fav = Fav(context: context)
                fav.name = name
                appDelegate.saveContext()
            }
            else{
                let checkName = array[rowSelected]

                for value in checkFav{
                    if value.name == checkName{
                        print("You already have this name ")

                    }
                    else {
                        let fav = Fav(context: context)
                        fav.name = name
                        appDelegate.saveContext()
                    }

                }

            }



        } catch{
            print("Error")
        }
```

Let's says I have two name "john","martha" in CoreData if I press to button of "martha" it shouldn't add again. But because of my loop when it sees "john" in the array it thinks this name isn't matching so it's saving "martha" (same name) to CoreData.

How can I check my checkFav array which contains the upcoming name if it contains don't save it again. But if not, add to CoreData. I'm really confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way to check for an empty entity cannot work if you want to save multiple records.

Add a predicate to the fetch request and a result limit of 1 to check for the specific name.

This method takes the name as parameter and adds a record if the name does not exist. It returns `true` if an entry is added otherwise false. Further it passes a potential error.

```
func addFavorite(for name : String) throws -> Bool {
    let request : NSFetchRequest<Fav> = Fav.fetchRequest()
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", name)
    request.resultsLimit = 1
    if let _ = try context.fetch(request).first {
       return false // record exists
    } else {
       let fav = Fav(context: context)
       fav.name = name
       appDelegate.saveContext()
       return true // record added
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you man it works like magic. I didn't know NSPredicate. I will search more

Comment: The magic is to read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FetchingObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH6-SW1)

Comment: Should i check apple's documentation first ? sometimes it looks too complicated to me? Because most of the time when i search something about ios programming, there is already youtube video or article which is probably most viewed and i look at them first. Am i doing wrong? or should i learn the basics from those videos and if i want to go deeper, check the documentation?  I am asking those because I have nobody nearby to ask

Comment: I'm new and everyday i learn something different and those will be more complex, and i don't follow any book or tutorial to guide me. Should i follow some book or tutorial or to learn by searching on internet?